# How to draw a NSView on a NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I am passed a NSView from a class and I need to add on another NSView at a certain point. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a view to another view by sending the addSubview message, like this:

```
[MyView addSubview:MyOtherView];
```

Don't forget though, you are responsible for how that view displays. Make sure you set its bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can position the new view when instantiating it using the initWithFrame: method that'll create the view and position it within the superview (i.e. the one you'll add your view to with the already mentioned addSubview: message).

PS: The [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978) - is your friend.. ;-)